# Menu border-color define in chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm new in css and html,I have problem with my menu.
Here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/VrG2C/9/
that is work correctly in firefox but have little problem with chrome
i think border-color is not correctly define. but i don't have any idea how can i fix it.

CSS

```
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
background: url("http://cssmenumaker.com/sites/default/files/menu/273/pattern.png") repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-color: #818176 -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color;
border-image: none;
border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
border-right: medium none;
border-style: solid none none;
border-width: 1px medium medium;
font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 300;
padding: 15px 10px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>SS</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Where is my mistake? and how can i fix it?

Thanks...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VrG2C/9/

Comment: If you take out the `-moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color` then the border color will apply. http://jsfiddle.net/VrG2C/10/

Comment: Yes work correctly
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
border-color: #818176;
```

Take out:

```
-moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color
```

If you take out that section then the border color will apply correctly.

[jsfiddle.net/VrG2C/10](http://jsfiddle.net/VrG2C/10)